# ClickOnce on CloudFront Update from Origin Site

Tags: clickonce, amazon-cloudfront

I have ClickOnce setup publish on my site. I'm using Amazon CloudFront to cache the files as close the clients as possible. The problem I now have to invalidate the app manifest every deployment.

Is it possible to have the ClickOnce check for update on one location yet download the app from another?

Thank you,
Ido

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to invalidate the manifest with each deployment? Is the CloudFront something like a CDN, where you need to tell the edge servers to retrieve a new version from the origin when it gets changed?

The ClickOnce app always downloads the files from the same location as the deployment manifest. And if I'm right and CF is some kind of CDN, then it's not the files that are the problem, it's the deployment maniest that's being picked up.

Also, the URL that ClickOnce uses to install and update from is part of the ID of the deployment, and it can't be changed willy-nilly. In most cases, your uses would have to uninstall and reinstall to access the deployment from a different URL.

On another note, you could avoid this whole problem and host your deployment in Azure blob storage for pennies a month (http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2011/07/18/host-your-clickonce-deployment-in-azure-for-pennies-per-month/) instead... You could even use the Azure CDN to give the speediest performance to your customers. On Azure, I think you can set the Time-To-Live to 0 on the deployment manifest to have it check each time it's accessed for an update.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't think of Azure for this, I'll read it and give it a shot. The reason I have to invalidate the deployment manifest is because CF is a CDN which cache the files on the edge servers so I have to let CF know the original file has changed.

Comment: Understood. We use a CDN for our deployments, and have to purge the deployment manifest after publishing a new version. With Azure, if you use blob storage, you don't have to do that. Also I think the TTL trick will work -- I got that directly from one of the Azure CDN program managers.